# How to compute the entropy of a random variable with values in a metric space?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, st.statistics, ergodic-theory, entropy

I have a cloud of points, and I want to compute its 'diversity'. Variance is not appropriate, because a cloud clustering around few points can still have a large variance.

To that end, I see the cloud of points as the realizations of a random variable.

I want to compute the topological entropy of a random variable, with values in a metric space $(X,d)$.

I only know $N$ (large) realisations of this variable,  and I can compute the relative distances between them.

Comment: see definition 2.5 in this [thesis](https://dspace.cuni.cz/bitstream/handle/20.500.11956/86228/BPTX_2016_1_11320_0_443355_0_177804.pdf?sequence=1)

Comment: Very uninformative comment.  It’s the Bowen-Dinaburg definition of entropy.I can't use it here because I don't know the whole map, only N realisations.

Comment: Perhaps you should give a bit more of context. Your question is a bit vague.

Comment: the context is that I have a cloud of points, and I want to measure its 'diversity' without using variance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Estimate the probability density, using [Kernel density estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation)
2. Compute the differential entropy.

Comment: Differential entropy with respect to **what**?